# Validate vaadin combobox custom input (integers only)

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin14

I have an input form with a combobox which displays integer values. I want the user to be able to add new integer values to this combobox. I need to **validate whether the input are only numbers** (and not letters) - if it isnt a valid integer I want to display an error message.

For textfields i figured it out quickly - i get an error message even while typing a "wrong" input! But i cannot find a solution for the combobox in combination with the addCustomValueSetListener.

I'm using Vaadin 14.1.21 and Java JDK+JRE 1.8.

Right now if I input a custom value with letters, I don't get an error message displayed beneath the box and it just silently ignores the input value when I want to "save" it / store it in the database.

```
public class MyForm extends Div {


    private TextField tf;
    tf =new TextField("TF");
    tf.setWidth("100%");
    tf.setRequired(true);
    tf.addThemeVariants(TextFieldVariant.LUMO_ALIGN_RIGHT);
    tf.setValueChangeMode(ValueChangeMode.EAGER);

    private ComboBox<Integer> combo_int;
    combo_int= new ComboBox<>();
    combo_int.setItems(114, 12383, 65432189);
    combo_int.setLabel("Some ID");
    combo_int.addCustomValueSetListener(
            event -> combo_int.setValue(Integer.parseInt(event.getDetail()))
            // since I need to parse new values here, I cannot use a validator upon binding
    );

    binder = new BeanValidationBinder<>(MyData.class);
    binder.forField(tf)
            .withNullRepresentation("")
            .withConverter(new StringToIntegerConverter("needs to be integer!"))
            .bind("tf_data_integer");

    binder.forField(combo_int)
            .bind("integer_data");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My final solution was to use Strings to display them in the frontend and build a custom Converter where I disable the "setGroupingUsed" to stop Vaadin from inserting thousands-seperators into my IDs in the UI.

Turns out it was easier than I thought, I just had to use a different data format for the UI than for the backend + a custom converter.

```
private static class Id_StringToInteger_Converter extends StringToIntegerConverter {

    public Id_StringToInteger_Converter() {
        super("Input has to be an Integer!");
    }

    @Override
    protected NumberFormat getFormat(Locale locale) {
        final NumberFormat format = super.getFormat(locale);
        format.setGroupingUsed(false); // disable thousands-seperator!
        return format;
    }
}

combo_int= new ComboBox<>();
combo_int.setItems("6583212", "114514", "879278");
combo_int.setLabel("Some ID");
combo_int.addCustomValueSetListener(event -> combo_int.setValue(event.getDetail()));


binder.forField(kreditoren_id)
      .withNullRepresentation("")
      .withConverter(new Id_StringToInteger_Converter())
      .bind("kreditoren_id");
```

Answer (score 0):

So i figured out a very dirty McGyver solution... but it still does not work 100%.

The main problem being that:

1. I have to parse (and hence validate) custom input in the addCustomValueSetListener
2. I cannot do it at the bean-binder as the custom input comes as a
       String and the bean-binder expectes an Integer
3. Using withConverter(StringToInteger) does not work as I still want
   to be able to select an Integer item
       from the Drop-Down menu.

So I had to

- build my own warning label
- reset the label manually upon switching
  between objects which are displayed in the form
- use setInvalid to highlight the wrong input & reset it after
- highjack the Validator to reset the status_label (to fix the issue of the label remaining if the user used the drop-down menu after selecting a wrong one - the label stayed...)

I still have the problem that binder.hasChanges() doesn't register an invalid input as a change as we catch it beforehand in the parser and it never makes it to the binder.

Perhaps I shall find a solution for that too, tomorrow.

```
    public class MyForm extends Div {

    private Label status_label = new Label();

    private TextField tf;
    tf =new TextField("TF");
    tf.setWidth("100%");
    tf.setRequired(true);
    tf.addThemeVariants(TextFieldVariant.LUMO_ALIGN_RIGHT);
    tf.setValueChangeMode(ValueChangeMode.EAGER);

    private ComboBox<Integer> combo_int;
    combo_int= new ComboBox<>();
    combo_int.setItems(114, 12383, 65432189);
    combo_int.setLabel("Some ID");
    combo_int.addCustomValueSetListener((event -> {            
            if (isInteger(event.getDetail())){
                status_label.setText(""); // reset on success  
                warengruppen_id.setValue(Integer.parseInt(event.getDetail()));
                warengruppen_id.setInvalid(false);
            } else {
                status_label.setText("Custom Format-Error!"); // set to error
                status_label.getStyle().set("color", "red");
                combo_int.setInvalid(true); // red background coloring
            }
        }
      );

    binder = new BeanValidationBinder<>(MyData.class);
    binder.forField(tf)
            .withNullRepresentation("")
            .withConverter(new StringToIntegerConverter("needs to be integer!"))
            .bind("tf_data_integer");

    binder.forField(combo_int).
             withValidator(event -> {
                    // we highjack the Validator to reset the field on correct input
                    status_label.setText("");
                    return true; // never raise the validator message
                }, "")
            .withNullRepresentation(null)
            .bind("integer_data");
    }
```